# How to use Link components in Menu.List elements

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, semantic-ui, semantic-ui-react

I'm trying to get a semantic ui (react) menu list, which should be working with react router, which means I would like to use the `Link` component of `react router`

If I use this...

```
<Menu.Item name='profile'>
    <Icon name='user' />
    My profile
</Menu.Item>
```

...it gives me the result:

```
<a class="item">
    <i aria-hidden="true" class="user icon"></i>
    My profile
</a>
```

But I would like to get something like

```
<Link to='profile'>
    <i aria-hidden="true" class="user icon"></i>
    My profile
</Link>
```

This one doesn't work, as the syntax is wrong:

```
<Menu.Item name='profile' as={ <Link to='profile' /> }>
    <Icon name='user' />
    My profile
</Menu.Item>
```

Answer (score 91, accepted):

You need use the SUIR's [augmentation](https://react.semantic-ui.com/#augmentation):

```
<Menu.Item as={ Link } name='profile' to='profile'>
  <Icon name='user' />
  My profile
</Menu.Item>
```

Comment: This also works with Button Like `<Button as={Link} to='/'>Home</Button>`

Comment: One note: Since the API has changed 'My profile' (String) needs to be wrapped inside a tags. Like this <a>My profile</a>

Answer (score 7):

Use `browserHistory.push` instead ; It  was provided also by `react-router` as an alternative of `Link` but non-markup :

```
import {browserHistory} from 'react-router';

redirect(to) {
    browserHistory.push({
       pathname: to
    });
} 
//......
<Menu.Item name="profile" onClick={this.redirect('/profile')}
    <Icon name='user' />
    My profile
</Menu.Item>
```

If you want to get `/profile` from `name` props  , change the line by :

```
<Menu.Item name="profile" onClick={(event, itemProps) => this.redirect(itemProps.name)}
```

And if so , `<Menu onItemClick={...} >` is better than `<Menu.item onClick={...} >`

Comment: Is there a difference between using `browserHistory.push({ pathname: to });` and `browserHistory.push(to);`?

Comment: It support [both](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/docs/API.md#pushpathorloc) however, `{pathname:to}` is better if you want to pass `query` also as well as other params